# How do dependency/attached properties work internally and where are values stored?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I'm a little bit unclear with all this magic. 
As I understood dependency properties get inherited from the DependencyObject, so values are stored:

- in the instance itself if value is assigned (in the local dictionary)
- or taken from the link to a parent element if value is not specified.

  ```
  protected object GetValue(string propertyName)
  {
     if (LocalValues.ContainsKey(propertyName))
     {
        return LocalValues[propertyName];
     }
     return Parent.GetValue(propertyName);
  }
  ```

  Am I correct in this?

I also don't understand where are values for attached properties stored?

```
Control.FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(
typeof(Control), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SystemFonts.MessageFontSize,
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

Does AddOwner method call on Attached property assigns value to the instance field? When does this happen and where does the value go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property system in WPF is pretty complex. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) really has a lot of information, but it is often hard to find. [While there are many ways a `DependencyProperty` can be set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), I'm not sure that you need to *care* where the values are stored.

For local values, you can assume that it is stored on the `DependencyObject` (again you shouldn't care where it is stored), with the caveat that they are not stored based on strings. It truly is associated with an instance of `DependencyProperty`. This is why you would want to add an owner to the property. If somebody sets `TextElement.FontSize` on your control, it is just like setting your local `FontSize` property.

As far as inheriting values for a property from a parent, this *only* happens with attached properties. From the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx) for `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions`:

> Although property value inheritance might appear to work for
>   nonattached dependency properties, the inheritance behavior for a
>   nonattached property through certain element boundaries in the runtime
>   tree is undefined. Always use RegisterAttached to register properties
>   where you specify Inherits in the metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Values for dependency properties are stored inside the objects (derived from DependencyObject) which we apply a property value to.

Let's take your TextElement.FontSizeProperty attached property for example:

```
<StackPanel TextElement.FontSize="20" ... >
  ...
</StackPanel>
```

XAML parser translates it to the following:

```
...
TextElement.SetFontSize(stackPanel, 20);
...
```

which is internally:

```
public static void SetFontSize(DependencyObject element, double value)
{
  element.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, value);
}
```

So, setting TextElement.FontSize on a stackPanel object is the same as calling

```
stackPanel.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, value)
```

SetValue() is a method defined in the DependencyObject class. Inside the method many complex things happen, but in the end the effective value of a dependency property is wrapped in a structure called EffectiveValueEntry and stored in the following instance field inside DependencyObject:

```
private EffectiveValueEntry[] _effectiveValues;
```